# Rendering a scene or prefab in a gallery style view in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, render, scene

I'm working on a project that is a bit like YouTube where someone browses some content, clicks on one and sees it in the youtube player while still seeing the rest of the content.

In my case the content is a Unity prefab that runs with interactions and gameplay, a bit like an interactive YouTube.

Is there a way to load these prefabs in a scene or something and have them displayed in a view port of some sort which substitutes the position of the player?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you can use 2 cameras. One for list one for clicked one. Use layers for 2 cameras. It will make all job a lot easier for you.

Comment: unfortunately this still has the issue of needing to position what is being rendered correctly in the camera so it appears in the right spot. I would much rather not have to worry about that.

Comment: @tweetypi Render to a texture. Create planes with these textures, arrange as desired.

Comment: How would the user interact with the planes?

Comment: @tweetypi what about making camera's child these objects? Maybe it can fix positioning issue.